# python parallel process list with data frames

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

I have a list that contains data frames. Inside a loop I iterate over this list cleanup each data frame in the list and dump to another list and return that list:

```
allDfs = []
def processDfs(self):

    for df in listOfDfs():
        for column_name in need_to_change_column_name:
            ...# some column name changes
        df.set_index('id', inplace=True)

        ## dropping any na
        df = df.dropna()
        ...

        df['cost'] = df['cost'].astype('float64')

        allDfs.append(df)

    return allDfs
```

How do I distribute processing of each data frame in the `listOfDfs` among multiple threads? and collect it and return list of process dfs.

Comment: I know this has been the traditional way to accelerate pandas by parallelization, but these days [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) resolves all of what you try to achieve "for free". You should consider using it if you can add this library in the packages you're allowed to use for your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the multiprocessing module:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

# enter the desired number of processes here
NUM_PROCS = 8    

def process_single_df(df):
    """
    Function that processes a single df.
    """
    for column_name in need_to_change_column_name:
        # some column name changes
        ...

    df.set_index('id', inplace=True)

    ## dropping any na
    df = df.dropna()
    ...

    df['cost'] = df['cost'].astype('float64')

    return df

pool = Pool(processes=NUM_PROCS)

allDfs = pool.map(process_single_df, listOfDfs)
```

The call to pool.map is blocking, meaning it will wait for all processes to complete before the program can continue.

If you don't need allDfs right away (you are happy to go ahead computing some other stuff while the parallel processing does its work) you can use `pool.map_async` instead in the last line:

```
# get async result instead (non-blocking)
async_result = pool.map_async(process_single_df, listOfDfs)
# do other stuff
...
# ok, now I need allDfs so will call async_result.get
allDfs = async_result.get()
```